# Append WHERE to query based on a condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a query like so:

```
if (catId == null || catId == 0)
{
    productVM = db.Products
                  .Include(x => x.Category)
                  .ToArray()
                  .Select(x => new ProductVM(x))
                  .ToList();
}
else
{
    productVM = db.Products
                  .Include(x => x.Category)
                  .ToArray()
                  .Where(x => x.CategoryId == catId)
                  .Select(x => new ProductVM(x))
                  .ToList();
}
```

That works, but as you can see the only difference between the 2 queries is `.Where(x => x.CategoryId == catId)`.

Is there a more elegant way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could expand the Where statement to include the test for null or 0 on catId. This might not work if the field catId in the database is nullable or can have a value of 0.

```
productVM = db.Products
    .Include(x => x.Category)
    .Where(x => catId == null || catId == 0 || x.CategoryId == catId)
    .Select(x => new ProductVM(x))
    .ToList();
```

Also you should remove the ToArray() as it queries the entire Products table from the database then perform the filtering and projecting in memory on the client.

Comment: This is probably a bad idea as it passes the `catId` checking to the database.

Comment: In our team we widely use this concept in SQL/Linq queries when the condition turns around a simple type, and works well.

Comment: @DavidG - Passing the condition to the database server is more optimum as it means a single execution plan will be created and used on the server regardless of the value of catId.

Comment: Actually that is completely wrong. Passing it to the server means you are passing a parameter that the server doesn't actually need and that query plan is optimised for only the situation where catId is null or not null. It's much preferable to have 2 query plans, one for each situation.

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework doesn't actually query the database until you materialise the data, for example with `ToList()` or iterating over the results. So you can build up your query as you go without hitting the database:

```
var query = db.Products.Include(x => x.Category);

if(catId != null && catId != 0)
{
    //Add a where clause
    query = query.Where(x => x.CategoryId == catId);
}

productVM = query
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new ProductVM(x));
```

Note that I removed the `ToArray` call as that also materialises the data which means each subsequent method on the data is acting on the entire table from the database.

Comment: This looks good however I get a red line saying basically `Cannot convert IQueryable to List`, and `productVM` is declared like so: `List<ProductVM> productVM;` I think i need some kind of a cast but not sure of the proper way?

Comment: Are you missing the `ToList` on the end of it?

Comment: the error is this: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CmsShoppingCart.Areas.Admin.Models.ViewModels.Shop.ProductVM>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CmsShoppingCart.Areas.Admin.Models.ViewModels.Shop.ProductVM>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: the red line appears under `db.Products.Include(x => x.Category);` and `query.Where(x => x.CategoryId == catId);`

Comment: Oops, I just saw a copy/paste error I made! Try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128566/discussion-between-frc-and-davidg).

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

```
var products = db.Products.Include(x => x.Category).ToArray()

if (catId == null || catId == 0)
{
    productVM = products.Select(x => new ProductVM(x)).ToList();
}
else
{
    productVM = products.Where(x => x.CategoryId == catId)
                        .Select(x => new ProductVM(x)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply re-assign query:

```
var query = db.Products;

if (condition)
    query = query.Where(criteria);

var list = query.ToList();
```